# Parallel Dynamic Programming with CUDA

Tags: dynamic, parallel-processing, cuda

It is my first attempt to implement recursion with CUDA. The goal is to extract all the combinations from a set of chars "12345" using the power of CUDA to parallelize dynamically the task. Here is my kernel:

```
__device__ char route[31] = { "_________________________"};
__device__ char init[6] = { "12345" };

__global__ void Recursive(int depth) {

    // up to depth 6
    if (depth == 5) return;     
    // newroute = route - idx

    int x = depth * 6;
    printf("%s\n", route);

    int o = 0;
    int newlen = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<6; ++i)
    {
        if (i != threadIdx.x)
        {
            route[i+x-o] = init[i];
            newlen++;
        }
        else                
        {
            o = 1;
        }
    }

    Recursive<<<1,newlen>>>(depth + 1);

}

__global__ void RecursiveCount() {
    Recursive <<<1,5>>>(0); 

}
```

The idea is to exclude 1 item (the item corresponding to the threadIdx) in each different thread. In each recursive call, using the variable depth, it works over a different base (variable x) on the route device variable.

I expect the kernel prompts something like:

2345_____________________

1345_____________________

1245_____________________

1234_____________________

2345_345_________________

2345_245_________________

2345_234_________________

2345_345__45_____________

2345_345__35_____________

2345_345__34_____________

..

2345_245__45_____________

..

But it prompts ...

·_____________

·_____________

·_____________

·_____________

·_____________

·2345

·2345

·2345

·2345

...

What I´m doing wrong?

Comment: if want debugging help, provide an [MCVE]. And a tip: C strings must be `\0` terminated

Comment: @talonmies this kernel is more than a minimal reproducible example, you only must paste this code and call to RecursiveCount() from host.

Comment: Should we guess how many threads you launch it with? If it is only a handful of addition lines of code to make it into an [MCVE], are you really too lazy to add them?

Comment: @talonmies you need to guess nothing. Recursive <<<1,5>>>(0); means 1 block and 5 threads, you can find this at main call. It is dynamic parallel programming ... you can learn more here: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-dynamic-parallelism-api-principles/

Comment: RecursiveCount is a kernel. you show no launch parameter. that is what I was referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by Robert Crovella is correct at the 5th point, the mistake was in the using of `init` in every recursive call, but I want to clarify something that can be useful for other beginners with CUDA.

I used this variable because when I tried to launch a child kernel passing a local variable I always got the exception: `Error: a pointer to local memory cannot be passed to a launch as an argument`.

As I´m C# expert developer I´m not used to using pointers (`Ref` does the low-level-work for that) so I thought there was no way to do it in CUDA/c programming.

As Robert shows in its code it is possible copying the pointer with `memalloc` for using it as a referable argument.

Here is a kernel simplified as an example of deep recursion.

```
__device__ char init[6] = { "12345" };

__global__ void Recursive(int depth, const char* route) {

    // up to depth 6
    if (depth == 5) return;

    //declaration for a referable argument (point 6)
    char* newroute = (char*)malloc(6); 
    memcpy(newroute, route, 5);

    int o = 0;
    int newlen = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (6 - depth); ++i)
    {
        if (i != threadIdx.x)
        {
            newroute[i - o] = route[i];
            newlen++;
        }
        else
        {
            o = 1;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", newroute);

    Recursive <<<1, newlen>>>(depth + 1, newroute);

}

__global__ void RecursiveCount() {
    Recursive <<<1, 5>>>(0, init);
}
```

I don't add the main call because I´m using ManagedCUDA for C# but as Robert says it can be figured-out how the call `RecursiveCount` is.

About ending arrays of char with `/0` ... sorry but I don't know exactly what is the benefit; this code works fine without them.

Answer (score 5):

> What I´m doing wrong?

I may not articulate every problem with your code, but these items should get you a lot closer.

1. I recommend providing a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  In my view it is basically required by Stack Overflow, see item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), note use of the word "must".  Your example is missing any host code, including the original kernel call.  It's only a few extra lines of code, why not include it?  Sure, in this case, I can deduce what the call must have been, but why not just include it?  Anyway, based on the output you indicated, it seems fairly evident the launch configuration of the host launch would have to be `<<<1,1>>>`.
2. This doesn't seem to be logical to me:

   > I expect the kernel prompts something like:
   >
   > 2345_____________________

   The very first thing your kernel does is print out the `route` variable, before making any changes to it, so I would expect `_____________________`.  However we can "fix" this by moving the printout to the end of the kernel.
3. You may be confused about what a `__device__` variable is.  It is a global variable, and there is only one copy of it.  Therefore, when you modify it in your kernel code, every thread, in every kernel, is attempting to modify the same global variable, at the same time.  That cannot possibly have orderly results, in any thread-parallel environment.  I chose to "fix" this by making a local copy for each thread to work on.
4. You have an off-by-1 error, as well as an extent error in this loop:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i<6; ++i)
   ```

   The off-by-1 error is due to the fact that you are iterating over 6 possible items (that is, `i` can reach a value of 5) but there are only 5 items in your `init` variable (the 6th item being a null terminator.  The correct indexing starts out over 0-4 (with one of those being skipped).  On subsequent iteration depths, its necessary to reduce this indexing extent by 1.  Note that I've chosen to fix the first error here by increasing the length of `init`.  There are other ways to fix, of course.  My method inserts an extra `_` between depths in the result.
5. You assume that at each iteration depth, the correct choice of items is the same, and in the same order, i.e. `init`.  However this is not the case.  At each depth, the choices of items must be selected not from the unchanging `init` variable, but from the choices passed from previous depth. Therefore we need a local, per-thread copy of `init` also.
6. A few other comments about [CUDA Dynamic Parallelism](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-dynamic-parallelism) (CDP).  When passing pointers to data from one kernel scope to a child scope, local space pointers cannot be used.  Therefore I allocate for the local copy of `route` from the heap, so it can be passed to child kernels.  `init` can be deduced from `route`, so we can use an ordinary local variable for `myinit`.
7. You're going to quickly hit some dynamic parallelism (and perhaps memory) limits here if you continue this.  I believe the total number of kernel launches for this is 5^5, which is 3125 (I'm doing this quickly, I may be mistaken).  CDP has a pending launch limit of 2000 kernels by default.  We're not hitting this here according to what I see, but you'll run into that sooner or later if you increase the depth or width of this operation.  Furthermore, in-kernel allocations from the device heap are by default limited to 8KB.  I don't seem to be hitting that limit, but probably I am, so my design should probably be modified to fix that.
8. Finally, in-kernel `printf` output is limited to the size of a particular buffer.  If this technique is not already hitting that limit, it will soon if you increase the width or depth.

Here is a worked example, attempting to address the various items above.  I'm not claiming it is defect free, but I think the output is closer to your expectations.  Note that due to character limits on SO answers, I've truncated/excerpted some of the output.

```
$ cat t1639.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ char route[31] = { "_________________________"};
__device__ char init[7] = { "12345_" };

__global__ void Recursive(int depth, const char *oroute) {


    char *nroute = (char *)malloc(31);
    char myinit[7];
    if (depth == 0) memcpy(myinit, init, 6);
    else memcpy(myinit, oroute+(depth-1)*6, 6);
    myinit[6] = 0;
    if (nroute == NULL) {printf("oops\n"); return;}
    memcpy(nroute, oroute, 30);
    nroute[30] = 0;
    // up to depth 6
    if (depth == 5) return;
    // newroute = route - idx

    int x = depth * 6;
    //printf("%s\n", nroute);

    int o = 0;
    int newlen = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<(6-depth); ++i)
    {
        if (i != threadIdx.x)
        {
            nroute[i+x-o] = myinit[i];
            newlen++;
        }
        else
        {
            o = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", nroute);

    Recursive<<<1,newlen>>>(depth + 1, nroute);

}

__global__ void RecursiveCount() {
    Recursive <<<1,5>>>(0, route);
}

int main(){

  RecursiveCount<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t1639 t1639.cu -rdc=true -lcudadevrt -arch=sm_70
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1639
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
2345_____________________
1345_____________________
1245_____________________
1235_____________________
1234_____________________
2345__345________________
2345__245________________
2345__235________________
2345__234________________
2345__2345_______________
2345__345___45___________
2345__345___35___________
2345__345___34___________
2345__345___345__________
2345__345___45____5______
2345__345___45____4______
2345__345___45____45_____
2345__345___45____5______
2345__345___45____5_____5
2345__345___45____4______
2345__345___45____4_____4
2345__345___45____45____5
2345__345___45____45____4
2345__345___35____5______
2345__345___35____3______
2345__345___35____35_____
2345__345___35____5______
2345__345___35____5_____5
2345__345___35____3______
2345__345___35____3_____3
2345__345___35____35____5
2345__345___35____35____3
2345__345___34____4______
2345__345___34____3______
2345__345___34____34_____
2345__345___34____4______
2345__345___34____4_____4
2345__345___34____3______
2345__345___34____3_____3
2345__345___34____34____4
2345__345___34____34____3
2345__345___345___45_____
2345__345___345___35_____
2345__345___345___34_____
2345__345___345___45____5
2345__345___345___45____4
2345__345___345___35____5
2345__345___345___35____3
2345__345___345___34____4
2345__345___345___34____3
2345__245___45___________
2345__245___25___________
2345__245___24___________
2345__245___245__________
2345__245___45____5______
2345__245___45____4______
2345__245___45____45_____
2345__245___45____5______
2345__245___45____5_____5
2345__245___45____4______
2345__245___45____4_____4
2345__245___45____45____5
2345__245___45____45____4
2345__245___25____5______
2345__245___25____2______
2345__245___25____25_____
2345__245___25____5______
2345__245___25____5_____5
2345__245___25____2______
2345__245___25____2_____2
2345__245___25____25____5
2345__245___25____25____2
2345__245___24____4______
2345__245___24____2______
2345__245___24____24_____
2345__245___24____4______
2345__245___24____4_____4
2345__245___24____2______
2345__245___24____2_____2
2345__245___24____24____4
2345__245___24____24____2
2345__245___245___45_____
2345__245___245___25_____
2345__245___245___24_____
2345__245___245___45____5
2345__245___245___45____4
2345__245___245___25____5
2345__245___245___25____2
2345__245___245___24____4
2345__245___245___24____2
2345__235___35___________
2345__235___25___________
2345__235___23___________
2345__235___235__________
2345__235___35____5______
2345__235___35____3______
2345__235___35____35_____
2345__235___35____5______
2345__235___35____5_____5
2345__235___35____3______
2345__235___35____3_____3
2345__235___35____35____5
2345__235___35____35____3
2345__235___25____5______
2345__235___25____2______
2345__235___25____25_____
2345__235___25____5______
2345__235___25____5_____5
2345__235___25____2______
2345__235___25____2_____2
2345__235___25____25____5
2345__235___25____25____2
2345__235___23____3______
2345__235___23____2______
2345__235___23____23_____
2345__235___23____3______
2345__235___23____3_____3
2345__235___23____2______
2345__235___23____2_____2
2345__235___23____23____3
2345__235___23____23____2
2345__235___235___35_____
2345__235___235___25_____
2345__235___235___23_____
2345__235___235___35____5
2345__235___235___35____3
2345__235___235___25____5
2345__235___235___25____2
2345__235___235___23____3
2345__235___235___23____2
2345__234___34___________
2345__234___24___________
2345__234___23___________
2345__234___234__________
2345__234___34____4______
2345__234___34____3______
2345__234___34____34_____
2345__234___34____4______
2345__234___34____4_____4
2345__234___34____3______
2345__234___34____3_____3
2345__234___34____34____4
2345__234___34____34____3
2345__234___24____4______
2345__234___24____2______
2345__234___24____24_____
2345__234___24____4______
2345__234___24____4_____4
2345__234___24____2______
2345__234___24____2_____2
2345__234___24____24____4
2345__234___24____24____2
2345__234___23____3______
2345__234___23____2______
2345__234___23____23_____
2345__234___23____3______
2345__234___23____3_____3
2345__234___23____2______
2345__234___23____2_____2
2345__234___23____23____3
2345__234___23____23____2
2345__234___234___34_____
2345__234___234___24_____
2345__234___234___23_____
2345__234___234___34____4
2345__234___234___34____3
2345__234___234___24____4
2345__234___234___24____2
2345__234___234___23____3
2345__234___234___23____2
2345__2345__345__________
2345__2345__245__________
2345__2345__235__________
2345__2345__234__________
2345__2345__345___45_____
2345__2345__345___35_____
2345__2345__345___34_____
2345__2345__345___45____5
2345__2345__345___45____4
2345__2345__345___35____5
2345__2345__345___35____3
2345__2345__345___34____4
2345__2345__345___34____3
2345__2345__245___45_____
2345__2345__245___25_____
2345__2345__245___24_____
2345__2345__245___45____5
2345__2345__245___45____4
2345__2345__245___25____5
2345__2345__245___25____2
2345__2345__245___24____4
2345__2345__245___24____2
2345__2345__235___35_____
2345__2345__235___25_____
2345__2345__235___23_____
2345__2345__235___35____5
2345__2345__235___35____3
2345__2345__235___25____5
2345__2345__235___25____2
2345__2345__235___23____3
2345__2345__235___23____2
2345__2345__234___34_____
2345__2345__234___24_____
2345__2345__234___23_____
2345__2345__234___34____4
2345__2345__234___34____3
2345__2345__234___24____4
2345__2345__234___24____2
2345__2345__234___23____3
2345__2345__234___23____2
1345__345________________
1345__145________________
1345__135________________
1345__134________________
1345__1345_______________
1345__345___45___________
1345__345___35___________
1345__345___34___________
1345__345___345__________
1345__345___45____5______
1345__345___45____4______
1345__345___45____45_____
1345__345___45____5______
1345__345___45____5_____5
1345__345___45____4______
1345__345___45____4_____4
1345__345___45____45____5
1345__345___45____45____4
1345__345___35____5______
1345__345___35____3______
1345__345___35____35_____
1345__345___35____5______
1345__345___35____5_____5
1345__345___35____3______
1345__345___35____3_____3
1345__345___35____35____5
1345__345___35____35____3
1345__345___34____4______
1345__345___34____3______
1345__345___34____34_____
1345__345___34____4______
1345__345___34____4_____4
1345__345___34____3______
1345__345___34____3_____3
1345__345___34____34____4
1345__345___34____34____3
1345__345___345___45_____
1345__345___345___35_____
1345__345___345___34_____
1345__345___345___45____5
1345__345___345___45____4
1345__345___345___35____5
1345__345___345___35____3
1345__345___345___34____4
1345__345___345___34____3
1345__145___45___________
1345__145___15___________
1345__145___14___________
1345__145___145__________
1345__145___45____5______
1345__145___45____4______
1345__145___45____45_____
1345__145___45____5______
1345__145___45____5_____5
1345__145___45____4______
1345__145___45____4_____4
1345__145___45____45____5
1345__145___45____45____4
1345__145___15____5______
1345__145___15____1______
1345__145___15____15_____
1345__145___15____5______
1345__145___15____5_____5
1345__145___15____1______
1345__145___15____1_____1
1345__145___15____15____5
1345__145___15____15____1
1345__145___14____4______
1345__145___14____1______
1345__145___14____14_____
1345__145___14____4______
1345__145___14____4_____4
1345__145___14____1______
1345__145___14____1_____1
1345__145___14____14____4
1345__145___14____14____1
1345__145___145___45_____
1345__145___145___15_____
1345__145___145___14_____
1345__145___145___45____5
1345__145___145___45____4
1345__145___145___15____5
1345__145___145___15____1
1345__145___145___14____4
1345__145___145___14____1
1345__135___35___________
1345__135___15___________
1345__135___13___________
1345__135___135__________
1345__135___35____5______
1345__135___35____3______
1345__135___35____35_____
1345__135___35____5______
1345__135___35____5_____5
1345__135___35____3______
1345__135___35____3_____3
1345__135___35____35____5
1345__135___35____35____3
1345__135___15____5______
1345__135___15____1______
1345__135___15____15_____
1345__135___15____5______
1345__135___15____5_____5
1345__135___15____1______
1345__135___15____1_____1
1345__135___15____15____5
1345__135___15____15____1
1345__135___13____3______
1345__135___13____1______
1345__135___13____13_____
1345__135___13____3______
1345__135___13____3_____3
1345__135___13____1______
1345__135___13____1_____1
1345__135___13____13____3
1345__135___13____13____1
1345__135___135___35_____
1345__135___135___15_____
1345__135___135___13_____
1345__135___135___35____5
1345__135___135___35____3
1345__135___135___15____5
1345__135___135___15____1
1345__135___135___13____3
1345__135___135___13____1
1345__134___34___________
1345__134___14___________
1345__134___13___________
1345__134___134__________
1345__134___34____4______
1345__134___34____3______
1345__134___34____34_____
1345__134___34____4______
1345__134___34____4_____4
1345__134___34____3______
1345__134___34____3_____3
1345__134___34____34____4
1345__134___34____34____3
1345__134___14____4______
1345__134___14____1______
1345__134___14____14_____
1345__134___14____4______
1345__134___14____4_____4
1345__134___14____1______
1345__134___14____1_____1
1345__134___14____14____4
1345__134___14____14____1
1345__134___13____3______
1345__134___13____1______
1345__134___13____13_____
1345__134___13____3______
1345__134___13____3_____3
1345__134___13____1______
1345__134___13____1_____1
1345__134___13____13____3
1345__134___13____13____1
1345__134___134___34_____
1345__134___134___14_____
1345__134___134___13_____
1345__134___134___34____4
1345__134___134___34____3
1345__134___134___14____4
1345__134___134___14____1
1345__134___134___13____3
1345__134___134___13____1
1345__1345__345__________
1345__1345__145__________
1345__1345__135__________
1345__1345__134__________
1345__1345__345___45_____
1345__1345__345___35_____
1345__1345__345___34_____
1345__1345__345___45____5
1345__1345__345___45____4
1345__1345__345___35____5
1345__1345__345___35____3
1345__1345__345___34____4
1345__1345__345___34____3
1345__1345__145___45_____
1345__1345__145___15_____
1345__1345__145___14_____
1345__1345__145___45____5
1345__1345__145___45____4
1345__1345__145___15____5
1345__1345__145___15____1
1345__1345__145___14____4
1345__1345__145___14____1
1345__1345__135___35_____
1345__1345__135___15_____
1345__1345__135___13_____
1345__1345__135___35____5
1345__1345__135___35____3
1345__1345__135___15____5
1345__1345__135___15____1
1345__1345__135___13____3
1345__1345__135___13____1
1345__1345__134___34_____
1345__1345__134___14_____
1345__1345__134___13_____
1345__1345__134___34____4
1345__1345__134___34____3
1345__1345__134___14____4
1345__1345__134___14____1
1345__1345__134___13____3
1345__1345__134___13____1
1245__245________________
1245__145________________
1245__125________________
1245__124________________
1245__1245_______________
1245__245___45___________
1245__245___25___________
1245__245___24___________
1245__245___245__________
1245__245___45____5______
1245__245___45____4______
1245__245___45____45_____
1245__245___45____5______
1245__245___45____5_____5
1245__245___45____4______
1245__245___45____4_____4
1245__245___45____45____5
1245__245___45____45____4
1245__245___25____5______
1245__245___25____2______
1245__245___25____25_____
1245__245___25____5______
1245__245___25____5_____5
1245__245___25____2______
1245__245___25____2_____2
1245__245___25____25____5
1245__245___25____25____2
1245__245___24____4______
1245__245___24____2______
1245__245___24____24_____
1245__245___24____4______
1245__245___24____4_____4
1245__245___24____2______
1245__245___24____2_____2
1245__245___24____24____4
1245__245___24____24____2
1245__245___245___45_____
1245__245___245___25_____
1245__245___245___24_____
1245__245___245___45____5
1245__245___245___45____4
1245__245___245___25____5
1245__245___245___25____2
1245__245___245___24____4
1245__245___245___24____2
1245__145___45___________
1245__145___15___________
1245__145___14___________
1245__145___145__________
1245__145___45____5______
1245__145___45____4______
1245__145___45____45_____
1245__145___45____5______
1245__145___45____5_____5
1245__145___45____4______
...
1235__1235__235___25_____
1235__1235__235___23_____
1235__1235__235___35____5
1235__1235__235___35____3
1235__1235__235___25____5
1235__1235__235___25____2
1235__1235__235___23____3
1235__1235__235___23____2
1235__1235__135___35_____
1235__1235__135___15_____
1235__1235__135___13_____
1235__1235__135___35____5
1235__1235__135___35____3
1235__1235__135___15____5
1235__1235__135___15____1
1235__1235__135___13____3
1235__1235__135___13____1
1235__1235__125___25_____
1235__1235__125___15_____
1235__1235__125___12_____
1235__1235__125___25____5
1235__1235__125___25____2
1235__1235__125___15____5
1235__1235__125___15____1
1235__1235__125___12____2
1235__1235__125___12____1
1235__1235__123___23_____
1235__1235__123___13_____
1235__1235__123___12_____
1235__1235__123___23____3
1235__1235__123___23____2
1235__1235__123___13____3
1235__1235__123___13____1
1235__1235__123___12____2
1235__1235__123___12____1
1234__234________________
1234__134________________
1234__124________________
1234__123________________
1234__1234_______________
1234__234___34___________
1234__234___24___________
1234__234___23___________
1234__234___234__________
1234__234___34____4______
1234__234___34____3______
1234__234___34____34_____
1234__234___34____4______
1234__234___34____4_____4
1234__234___34____3______
1234__234___34____3_____3
1234__234___34____34____4
1234__234___34____34____3
1234__234___24____4______
1234__234___24____2______
1234__234___24____24_____
1234__234___24____4______
1234__234___24____4_____4
1234__234___24____2______
1234__234___24____2_____2
1234__234___24____24____4
1234__234___24____24____2
1234__234___23____3______
1234__234___23____2______
1234__234___23____23_____
1234__234___23____3______
1234__234___23____3_____3
1234__234___23____2______
1234__234___23____2_____2
1234__234___23____23____3
1234__234___23____23____2
1234__234___234___34_____
1234__234___234___24_____
1234__234___234___23_____
1234__234___234___34____4
1234__234___234___34____3
1234__234___234___24____4
1234__234___234___24____2
1234__234___234___23____3
1234__234___234___23____2
1234__134___34___________
1234__134___14___________
1234__134___13___________
1234__134___134__________
1234__134___34____4______
1234__134___34____3______
1234__134___34____34_____
1234__134___34____4______
1234__134___34____4_____4
1234__134___34____3______
1234__134___34____3_____3
1234__134___34____34____4
1234__134___34____34____3
1234__134___14____4______
1234__134___14____1______
1234__134___14____14_____
1234__134___14____4______
1234__134___14____4_____4
1234__134___14____1______
1234__134___14____1_____1
1234__134___14____14____4
1234__134___14____14____1
1234__134___13____3______
1234__134___13____1______
1234__134___13____13_____
1234__134___13____3______
1234__134___13____3_____3
1234__134___13____1______
1234__134___13____1_____1
1234__134___13____13____3
1234__134___13____13____1
1234__134___134___34_____
1234__134___134___14_____
1234__134___134___13_____
1234__134___134___34____4
1234__134___134___34____3
1234__134___134___14____4
1234__134___134___14____1
1234__134___134___13____3
1234__134___134___13____1
1234__124___24___________
1234__124___14___________
1234__124___12___________
1234__124___124__________
1234__124___24____4______
1234__124___24____2______
1234__124___24____24_____
1234__124___24____4______
1234__124___24____4_____4
1234__124___24____2______
1234__124___24____2_____2
1234__124___24____24____4
1234__124___24____24____2
1234__124___14____4______
1234__124___14____1______
1234__124___14____14_____
1234__124___14____4______
1234__124___14____4_____4
1234__124___14____1______
1234__124___14____1_____1
1234__124___14____14____4
1234__124___14____14____1
1234__124___12____2______
1234__124___12____1______
1234__124___12____12_____
1234__124___12____2______
1234__124___12____2_____2
1234__124___12____1______
1234__124___12____1_____1
1234__124___12____12____2
1234__124___12____12____1
1234__124___124___24_____
1234__124___124___14_____
1234__124___124___12_____
1234__124___124___24____4
1234__124___124___24____2
1234__124___124___14____4
1234__124___124___14____1
1234__124___124___12____2
1234__124___124___12____1
1234__123___23___________
1234__123___13___________
1234__123___12___________
1234__123___123__________
1234__123___23____3______
1234__123___23____2______
1234__123___23____23_____
1234__123___23____3______
1234__123___23____3_____3
1234__123___23____2______
1234__123___23____2_____2
1234__123___23____23____3
1234__123___23____23____2
1234__123___13____3______
1234__123___13____1______
1234__123___13____13_____
1234__123___13____3______
1234__123___13____3_____3
1234__123___13____1______
1234__123___13____1_____1
1234__123___13____13____3
1234__123___13____13____1
1234__123___12____2______
1234__123___12____1______
1234__123___12____12_____
1234__123___12____2______
1234__123___12____2_____2
1234__123___12____1______
1234__123___12____1_____1
1234__123___12____12____2
1234__123___12____12____1
1234__123___123___23_____
1234__123___123___13_____
1234__123___123___12_____
1234__123___123___23____3
1234__123___123___23____2
1234__123___123___13____3
1234__123___123___13____1
1234__123___123___12____2
1234__123___123___12____1
1234__1234__234__________
1234__1234__134__________
1234__1234__124__________
1234__1234__123__________
1234__1234__234___34_____
1234__1234__234___24_____
1234__1234__234___23_____
1234__1234__234___34____4
1234__1234__234___34____3
1234__1234__234___24____4
1234__1234__234___24____2
1234__1234__234___23____3
1234__1234__234___23____2
1234__1234__134___34_____
1234__1234__134___14_____
1234__1234__134___13_____
1234__1234__134___34____4
1234__1234__134___34____3
1234__1234__134___14____4
1234__1234__134___14____1
1234__1234__134___13____3
1234__1234__134___13____1
1234__1234__124___24_____
1234__1234__124___14_____
1234__1234__124___12_____
1234__1234__124___24____4
1234__1234__124___24____2
1234__1234__124___14____4
1234__1234__124___14____1
1234__1234__124___12____2
1234__1234__124___12____1
1234__1234__123___23_____
1234__1234__123___13_____
1234__1234__123___12_____
1234__1234__123___23____3
1234__1234__123___23____2
1234__1234__123___13____3
1234__1234__123___13____1
1234__1234__123___12____2
1234__1234__123___12____1
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: there is still the undefined behaviour with the printf. route should be zero terminated for correctness

Comment: I attempted to zero-terminate both `nroute` and `myinit` in my code, although I did not enumerate it in my list of comments.  It's possible I still have a logical error here.  I avoid concerns about zero-termination of `route` itself by copying it into `nroute` before I use it, and `nroute` is zero-terminated.

Comment: sorry I missed the zero termination you added to nroute after copying to it

Comment: @RobertCrovella ... you have found the mistake (point 5) and you help me to understand how to pass values from parents to childs (point 6) wht lead me to the mistake. Thx a lot.

Comment: I wouldn't focus merely on point 5.  Points 3, 4, 5 are all logical errors that have very little to do with CUDA, but represent a failure of using recursion techniques, or general programming, correctly.  Any one of the issues in points 3,4,5 will cause your program output to deviate significantly from your stated goal.  There are approximately 4 mistakes in there.  I wouldn't want to communicate to future readers that the only thing that matters is point 5, or points 5 and 6.

Comment: @RobertCrovella points 3 and 4 are not errors. I did it intentionally, and the 5th was in consequence of the 6th. You can understand it looking at my answer.